# Why isn't my Area Light showing up, and why is my scene not rendering?

Tags: rendering, lighting

I started using Blender a few days ago, wanting to create an animation for a logo. My basic idea involves an angled gear spinning and a light flash across a trail to an airplane, and for the most part, I've been able to get that to work. However, the area light for the light flash doesn't illuminate the trail, and I'm not sure why. I've tried setting the power to a huge amount but I still had no luck. Additionally, when I try to render the scene, I only get a blank screen. Could someone please help me figure this out? Thank you.

[image: The project. You can see the Area Lamp is not illuminating the trail.]
[image: The render tab shows a blank screen]
[image: Top view of layout]

Here's the file:
[image]

Comment: First off, in the first image, you are in _Material Preview_ mode which uses false (preset) lighting to better "show off" materials, but not lights. Switch to _rendered preview_ mode (press Z in the 3D viewport and pick it from the pie menu) to see  your lights. As for the camera, make sure it is set properly (get a distance/angle you like in the 3D viewport and press Ctrl+Alt+Numpad0). Lastly, if that doesn't work, make sure the camera's _end clip distance_ is set far enough (Press N to bring up the tool menu, then select the "View" tab on the right and change the End value).